# Wifi not working / hardware, how to connect to the internet

Tags: reverse-tether

i have an Asus K011 Tablet, which i want to connect to the internet. Hovewer wifi is damaged on the motherboard as well as bluetooth so the only possibillity is ot connect it via USB cable to my laptop and from laptop share the internet to the tablet. How can i do it , which program i should use? 
Thanks for the answers

Comment: It's called reverse tethering: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=reverse%20tether

Answer (score 2):

Use reverse usb thethering through android VPN api.

This project can do that:
https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet
. No root required.

It is creating a tun0 network interface. ipv4 with tcp/udp will work.

Comment: This is the best one out there

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10 x64 — not sure if any other hardware/firmware/etc limitations might apply — you can navigate to `Ethernet Properties` dialogue window...

[image: Wired Connection]

...for wired, and `Mobile hotspot` system settings window...

[image: Wireless Connection]...

for wireless internet sharing.  Though I've never utilized these features myself and can't speak for how well they work, note that (at least for me) they came standard with my build and I did not need to download or utilize any 3rd party software or utility.  Hope that helps!